# Conversion from Base 64 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, base64

I'm trying to convert from a Base64 string. First I tried this:

```
string a = "BTQmJiI6JzFkZ2ZhY";
byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(a);
string c = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b);
```

Then got the exception - System.FormatException was caught Message=Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.

So after googling,I tried this:

```
string a1 = "BTQmJiI6JzFkZ2ZhY";
int mod4 = a1.Length % 4;
if (mod4 > 0)
{
    a1 += new string('=', 4 - mod4);
}
byte[] b1 = Convert.FromBase64String(a1);
string c1 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b1);
```

Here I got the exception - System.FormatException was caught Message=Invalid character in a Base-64 string.

Is there any invalid character in "BTQmJiI6JzFkZ2ZhY"? Or is it the length issue?

EDIT: I first decrypt the input string using the below code:

```
string sourstr, deststr,strchar;
int strlen;
decimal ascvalue, ConvValue;

deststr = "";
sourstr = "InputString";
strlen = sourstr.Length;

for (int intI = 0; intI <= strlen - 1; intI++)
{
    strchar = sourstr.Substring(intI, 1);
    ascvalue = (decimal)strchar[0];
    ConvValue = (decimal)((int)ascvalue ^ 85);

    if ((char)ConvValue.ToString().Length == 0)
    {
        deststr = deststr + strchar;
    }
    else
    {
        deststr = deststr + (char)ConvValue;
    }
}
```

This output deststr is passed to below code

```
Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(deststr));
```

This is where I got "BTQmJiI6JzFkZ2ZhY"

Comment: Try this `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b)`

Comment: Might be a padding issue? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table says while in theory it is not needed for decoding, some implementations insist on it nevertheless.

Comment: i tried decoding it else where as UTF-8 and got `4&&":'1dgfa` Theres a non-printable char in there.

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm getting the above exception in the code. Any idea why I'm getting this. I tried an online decode. There I got the result 4&&":'1dgfa.

Comment: Base64 of `4&&":'1dgfa` should be `NCYmIjonMWRnZmE=`. Decoding yours gives me `[]4&&":'1dgfa` in a browser (`[]` as replacement for the non-displayable byte value character), and if I apply URL encoding, it shows as `"%054%26...`, so you have a `05` byte value there before your `4` character. Whether that makes sense, I guess only the person who encoded the original value could tell you.

Comment: im just questioning where @kingfisher got that string from.

Comment: @PCs Error is at Convert.FromBase64String()

Comment: The issue is with your mod 4 calculation as that is returning 1 which means you are padding with `===`. The first `=` is invalid as there only needs to be up to two padding characters.

Comment: Try taking original string and converting to base 64 string to understand the issue.  Most cases when this occurs the data is being transferred between two PCs and not all the data gets received.

Comment: @DanielA.White This was encoded by my application itself. At first I thought the string may be manually entered by someone in the DB. But there are few more strings like this where I get the same error.

Comment: share that code then. something seems wrong.

Comment: A valid base64 string is a multiple of 4 with _at most_ 2 padding chars. So 17 chars without padding cannot be valid b64.

Comment: @jdweng Actually I dont know any of the original string, these are the values stored in DB some time ago.

Comment: @spodger When I padded with 2 == ie "BTQmJiI6JzFkZ2ZhY==", the total length will be 19 which is not a multiple of 4. So I get the same Invalid length exception

Comment: You cannot get such string by converting whole number of bytes to base64.

Comment: @kingfisher, yes, I think I may have been hasty. I don't think your string is valid Base64 as there is no valid length padding which makes it work.

Comment: @DanielA.White Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str));

Comment: @spodger If it happened only once its ok....but it has happened few times...thats the problem for me :(

Comment: Do you have the code the put data into database?  You can try a test with new data.  It is possible the data is encrypted and that is why you are getting the errors.

Comment: @jdweng Added the code above

Comment: You need to get the encryption code to validate the decryption code.  The error indicates the decryption code isn't working correctly or you do not need to convert from a base 64 string after you do the decryption.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get such base64 string by encoding whole number of bytes. While encoding, every 3 bytes are represented as 4 characters, because 3 bytes is 24 bits, and each base64 character is 6 bits (2^6=64), so 4 of them is also 24 bits. If number of bytes to encode is not divisable by 3 - you have some bytes left. You can have 2 or 1 bytes left.

If you have 2 bytes left - that's 16 bits and you need at least 3 characters to encode that (2 characters is just 12 bits - not enough). So in case you have 2 bytes left - you encode them with 3 characters and apply "=" padding.

If you have 1 byte left - that's 8 bits. You need at least 2 characters for that. You encode to 2 characters and apply "==" padding.

Note that there is no way to encode something to just one character (and for that reason - there is no "===" padding).

Your string can be divided in 4 character blocks: "BTQm", "JiI6", "JzFk", "Z2Zh", "Y". 4 first blocks each represent 3 bytes, but what "Y" represents? Who knows. You can say that it represents 1 byte in range 0-63, but from above you can see that's not how it works, so to interpret it like that you have to do it yourself.

From above you can see that you cannot get base64 string with length 17 (without padding). You can get 16, 18, 19, 20, but never 17

Comment: Got these type of strings few times

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you took all chars from base64 output?
Appending "==" at the end of the string will make your first approach work without any problems. Although there is strange character at the beginning of the output. So the next question is: Are you sure it is "ASCI" Encoding?